# Discontinuities of an injective function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

It is well known that a monotonic function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ can have only countably many discontinuities.

**Question:** Is it true that an injective function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ can have countable many discontinuities?

Comment: $f(x)=x$, $x$ rational, $f(x)=x+1$, $x$ irrational.

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample was given by [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377777/discontinuities-of-an-injective-funtion-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbr#comment2805191_1377777): 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,\quad & x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ x+1 , \quad  &x\notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$
This is an everywhere discontinuous bijection, the inverse being 
$$f^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}x,\quad & x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ x-1 , \quad  &x\notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$